# How to DeActivate feature of my site?

Tags: feature, site-collection, sandbox-solution

How to DeActivate feature of my SharePoint site remotely ?

I have created .wsp package file and uploaded SandBox solution to my SharePoint site. But in my elements.xml file it has 1 mistake of JavaScript's path file.

So after activating that feature, I am not able to see any page.
And getting following error,

> 'Cannot make a cache safe URL for
>   "/ProjectName/jscript/Myjscriptfile.js", file not found. Please verify
>   that the file exists under the layouts directory.'

So How to Remove/DeActivate this feature ?

OR How to Retract/Remove solution from Central Administration ? Because I am using my site remotely with Admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retract a feature on the server using central admin,

in 2007.

open up central admin -> click on operations -> under "global configuration" select solution managment.

find the feature wsp and retract :)

There is a huge issue tho without first deactivating the feature, why? becuase if you retract without deactivating it will keep an instance on the sharepoint site, So when you go to add the feature back again it will have two instances of the same feature even tho you only have one wsp and one in the features list.

a better way in 2010 and 2007 is using stsadm to deactivate the feature and then remove it:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -filename FeatureNameFolder\feature.xml -force -url http://site
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -filename

stsadm -o retractsolution -name YourWSP.wsp -url http://site -immediate
 stsadm -o deletesolution -name YourWSP.wsp
```

http://www.denisstadler.com/sharepoint-2010/install-and-uninstall-a-feature-in-sharepoint-using-stsadm-exe/